# Use external link in the add sub menu

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions

I want to show the data in the external plugins.php file. the below url path is correct but its not showing the file data. Whats the problem?

```
add_submenu_page( 'antify', 'Plugins', 'Plugins', 'manage_options', 'plugins', ANTIFY_PLUGIN_URL . '/admin/pages/plugins.php' );
```

**plugins.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Comment: What the `ANTIFY_PLUGIN_URL` is producing?

Comment: thats the total url: localhost/Antify/wp-content/plugins/antify/admin/pages/plugins.php

Comment: The last argument accepts callback, not file path. You are mixing something up here.

Comment: then how do i use the php file ? i want a separate file for the sub menu pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last argument of function `add_submenu_page` is the name of the function to call when display the content of the page. As described here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

The right use is:

```
add_submenu_page( 'antify', 'Plugins', 'Plugins', 'manage_options', 'plugins', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
  echo 'hello';
}
```

If you want a separate file you can do this

```
add_submenu_page( 'antify', 'Plugins', 'Plugins', 'manage_options', 'plugins', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
  include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'path/of/file.php';
}
```

Comment: why this not accepting the url path(www.localhost.com/...) but is accepting the directory path(c:/localhost/www/...).

Comment: The php statement `include` require absolute or relative path of the file to include. It works server-side so it doesn't use URL. Thi is the php documentation 
http://php.net/manual/it/function.include.php